# Find $f(x)$ from the differential equation $f(x)+{f}'(x) = x^{3} +5x^{2} +x +2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

find $f(x)$ from
$f(x)+{f}'(x) = x^{3} +5x^{2} +x +2$.
I tried to impose $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ but i can not solve it.

Comment: That is a first order linear differential equation. Have you tried find the integrating factor?

Comment: This is a first order differential equation with integrating factor $e^x$ and a  really long resulting integral..

Comment: Hoping not a careless mistake solution can be $f(x)=x^3+2x^2-3x+5+C e^{-x}$

Comment: Alternatively, assume $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial, and solve for the coefficients. (Note that if $f(x)$ is a solution, so is $f(x)+Ce^{-x}$…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If f(x) is a polynomial,

Let $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

Then $f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$

Therefore $f(x)+f'(x)=ax^3+(3a+b)x^2+(2b+c)x+(c+d)$

$a=1, b=2, c=-3,d=5$

**EDIT**

If $f(x)$ is partially polynomial.

Let $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$, where $g(x)$ is polynomial and $h(x)$ is non-polynomial,

$f'(x)=g'(x)+h'(x)$

when $f(x)+f'(x)=[g(x)+g'(x)]+[h'(x)+h(x)]=G(x)+H(x)$

where $G(x)=x^3+5x^2+x+2$

And for any  ${x:h(x)+h'(x)=0}$, the non-polynomial part is cancelled.

e.g. $h(x)=e^{-x}, h'(x)=-e^{-x}$

$f(x)=x^3+5x^2+x+2+h(x)$

Comment: First you should prove that $f$ is polynomial.

Comment: why should $f$ be a polynomial?

Comment: If the initial value, $f(0)$, is not zero, then this will have a transient solution with a decaying exponential.

Comment: @Joel Although my answer is selected, but I actually missed the part you all have mentioned. Before edition I also think that Joel's ans is better. But after edition, can someone see will it be possible that my ans is also valid?

Comment: @k1.M, $f$ must be at least be partially polynomial for $f' + f$ to be a polynomial. At least the particular solution will be a polynomial, because we know that the homogeneous solution does not contribute to the RHS.

Comment: No need to give me credit. What's important is which answer the OP gets the most value out of. Your edit is correct, and is probably closer to what the OP needs. Your first step in finding a solution in terms of polynomials provided a "particular solution". This can differ from the general solution by a solution to the homogenous differential equation $f(x)+f'(x)=0$. Thus if you take your particular solution, the addition of a homogenous solution will not affect the result of the differential equation.

Answer (score 9):

Note that $$e^x f(x) + e^x f'(x) = (e^x f(x))'$$

So if we multiply both sides of your equation by $e^x$ we have:

$$(e^x f(x))' = x^3e^x+5x^2 e^{x} + xe^x + 2e^x$$

So the solution can be found through integration:

$$e^x f(x) - e^{0}f(0) = \int_0^x (t^3 e^t + 5t^2 e^t + te^t + 2e^t) dt$$ and the right hand side can be evaluated using integration by parts. Finally you will need to multiply both sides by $e^{-x}$ to solve for $f(x)$:

$$f(x) = e^{-x} f(0) + e^{-x} \cdot \int_0^x (t^3 e^t + 5t^2 e^t + te^t + 2e^t) dt.$$

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x^3+2x^2-3x+5$ is a solution.  This can be obtained by guessing a degree 3 polynomial will work, and then working one coefficient at a time.

For example, lead coefficient must be 1.  Then derivative of $x^3$ is $3x^2$, so I still need $2x^2$.  This must be the second term.  Continue until you know all coefficients.

Solution of the homogeneous form $f(x) + f'(x)=0$ is seen to be $Ce^{-x}$ fairly easily.

So $x^3+2x^2-3x+5+Ce^{-x}$ is the general solution.

Comment: Wow, and I actually integrated by parts thrice, I feel weird now. haha

Answer (score 2):

for the equation $y'(x)+y(x)=0$ you will get $y(x)=Ce^{-x}$ and for the inhomogeneous part make the ansatz
$y(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$

Answer (score 1):

A method suitable for lazy people. We can write the particular solution formally  as:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+D}\left(x^3 +5x^2 + x + 2\right)$$

where $D$ is the differential operator. If we substitute the formal expansion:

$$\frac{1}{1+D} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k D^k$$

then this yields:

$$f(x) = x^3 +2 x^2 -3 x +5$$

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easier to use the method undetermined coefficients

The complementary solution that solves the homogeneous equation is
$$ y_c(x) = Ce^{-x} $$

The particular solution can be found by setting
$$ y_p(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D $$

Taking the derivative and plugging back into the equation
$$ Y_p' = 3Ax^2 + 2Bx + c$$
$$ y_P' + y_p = Ax^3 + (3A+B)x^2 + (2B+C)x + (C+D) =x^3 + 5x^2 + x + 2 $$

Equating the coefficients will give you values of $A,B,C,D$
$$ \begin{cases} A = 1 \\ 3A+B = 5 \\ 2B+C = 1 \\ C+D = 2 \end{cases}$$

Finally, the general solution is
$$ y_g(x) = y_c(x) + y_p(x) $$